# Using jQuery and Semantic-ui in Webpack Angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, semantic-ui

I am having problems trying to use jquery with semantic ui.

I want to use:

```
$('.ui.modal').modal('show');
```

But doesn't work, visual say: Property 'modal' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.

I don't know how to make that JQuery works with semantic ui because I want to use some things that requires JQuery to work with.

Other elements from semantic ui works but the Jquery doesn't work so I can't use some functions.

Comment: check this:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41806998/semantic-ui-with-angular2-how-to-set-sidebar-settings-from-jquery-in-a-compone/41821741#41821741

Comment: or http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/dbaskin/yes-used-jquery-angular2-application